# Standard way of retrieving PHP Form Inputs

Tags: php, forms, user-input

I have been doing web programming with PHP for about 2 months,and for forms, I have been retrieving user input in a manner such as this:

For standard `<input type="text">`:

```
/*input sanitation*/
function testInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}

/*just gets the data*/
function getRText($HTMLname) {

if (isset ( $_POST [$HTMLname] ) && ! empty ( $_POST [$HTMLname] )) {
    return testInput(( $_POST [$HTMLname] ));
} else {
    throw new Exception("Input is missing from " + $HTMLname);
}
}
```

And then, on another script, I'd do something like this:

```
$userID = getRText('uid');
$company = getRText('company');
$projectNum = getRText('projnum');

$dataArray = array($userID, $company, $projectNum);
```

The problem with this approach is it's very time consuming when I have a large form. I'm thinking in Perl (using Perl CGI), I'd be able to dynamically loop across the user input fields, and add each input into an array dynamically, but I'm not sure if something like this is possible in PHP. Right now, I'm currently having to manually pull each data from each input. All the PHP form examples online do it in this manner as well. Is this the correct way of pulling data from PHP forms?

Comment: Isn't all the input already in an array? If you're going to go through all that, just sanitize $_POST.

Comment: I think a simple beginner's form tutorial will be helpful as well: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: Also you dont need to do an `isset()` and an `empty()` as `empty()` implies an `isset()`. [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: @castis oh, I never realized $_POST was an array. Thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly -- except for 0, or false, or blank. Empty strings and the number 0 are valid inputs from a form in many cases. In fact, the only desirable case for "empty()" on a form would be the "isset", in which case you might as well be using isset anyway<edit:>,without empty.

Comment: @JacobS Please tell me how you get a form to pass `boolean false` to a script, or 0 as an integer, and I think blank means the field is empty????

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry -- I assumed that you were aware that empty("0") is true, as well as empty(""), which was the reason I said "Empty strings and the number 0 are valid inputs from a form in many cases". Edit: "I think blank means the field is empty" -- certainly does, but assumption and not understanding the truths simply leads to bad programming. Never assume something when sanitizing an input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data from a form is delivered to your script in either the $_POST or $_GET **array**.

So you could simply do

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    $_POST[$key] = testInput($val);
}
```

This will run your sanitization and place the data back into the $_POST array therefore removing the need for yet another array.

I never did understand why people move data from the $_POST/$_GET array to scalar variables or other arrays. Its a perfectly good array and once delivered to you its all yours to do whatever you like with.

Comment: "I never did understand ..." -- simple. What check, in your example, tells you that POST has actually been sanitized and that someone didn't forget to include the sanitization code somewhere, or didn't accidentally disable it. Always better to know it was santized by accessing it from a source that only contains sanitized data rather than the "cross your fingers and hope it continues to work correctly" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can still dynamically loop across input in PHP as well. This would do what you wanted:

```
$input_array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    $input_array[] = getRText($val);
}
```